# Exporting multiple components through HOC from a single ES6 module

Tags: javascript, es6-modules

I'm used to writing my React components in a fashion similar to this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import withStyles from 'react-jss';

const styles = theme => ({
    // my styles
});

class MyComponent extends Component {
    render() {
        // my render function
    }
};

export default withStyles(styles)(MyComponent);
```

I'm trying to add a second component in this same file. I would like to have it in the same file for reasons*. I defined the class `MyComponent2` in pretty much the same way, but now **I don't know how I should export it**, considering that also `MyComponent2` must be decorated with the `withStyles` HOC.

Here is what I tried (it's marked as an error):

```
export withStyles(styles)(MyComponent2); 
export const withStyles(styles)(MyComponent2); 
export const MyComponent2 = withStyles(styles)(MyComponent2); // of course I'm redefining MyComponent2
```

^* I know I could just put it in another file, but I want to know how to do this in case some day I have very compelling reasons.

Comment: When exporting different things, you will need to give them names to distinguish them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd go with:

```
  export const MyComponent = withStyles(class MyComponent extends Component {
     render() {
         // my render function
     }
  });
```

That way, the names don't clash as the class is a class expression and not a class declaration.

> for reasons*

I can't think of any. It makes sense to split the components into multiple files.

Comment: What if I have certain shared variables (configuration, styles...) that I don't want to export? They could live inside the module (the file), be visible to all the classes defined in that module, and invisible externally.

Comment: Move them into another file, then import them in both component files? For sure that won't be "private", but with naming conventions e.g. `_styles.js` you could make sure that it won't get used by others.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you'll want to use

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import withStyles from 'react-jss';

const styles = theme => ({
    // my styles
});

export const MyComponent1 = withStyles(styles)(class extends Component {
    render() {
        // my render function
    }
});

export const MyComponent2 = withStyles(styles)(class extends Component {
    render() {
        // my render function
    }
});
```

Comment: I'm not a big fan of this style, as I would like it more to have the HOC declared separately, but it has the advantage of not requiring two names for the class. I think I'll accept @JonasWhilm's answer that came a little earlier than yours, but thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You can have multiple named exports per file.

```js
export const Component1 = withStyles(styles)(MyComponent1);
export const Component2 = withStyles(styles)(MyComponent2);

// or
export default {
    MyComponent1 : withStyles(styles)(MyComponent1),
    MyComponent2 : withStyles(styles)(MyComponent2)
}
```

Comment: ...but I have to come up with an "internal" name and a "public" one that gets exported, right?

Comment: Yes, or you can export an object.

Comment: I like your last suggestion: it creates a sort of namespace that would be really useful in certain occasions. However, in the general case I'm afraid I will have to stick with @JonasWilms's answer. Thank you very much!